# Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

i am trying to loop over an array but when the array is empty i am receiving the following error

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

for the very first time and  when the data is inserted in an array or say the array is not empty then the error goes away 
Here is the screenshot

**https://ibb.co/gvCy4Cv**
and then when any data is entered in the array we do not see the error,below is the screenshot of that too

**https://ibb.co/0h4G9mM** //see that last two entries in console

Below is the code for this

.component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from 'src/app/services/items.service';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})

export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription:Subscription
  categories:any[]=[]
  default="Bread"
  constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
  prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
  route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription=this.prservice.fetchproducts.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        // console.log(data)
        this.categories=data
        console.log(this.categories)
      })
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }

  headElements = ['Title', 'Price', ''];
}
```

html file

```html
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" [routerLink]=" . 
['/admin/products/new']" mdbWavesEffect>New Products</button>
<table mdbTable >
<thead >
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of categories">
    <td>{{el?.title}}</td>
    <td>{{el?.price}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To make sure that it's caused by the first ***ngFor**, can you remove  entire `<tbody>` from your template and check whether error stays

Answer (score 0):

use `*ngIf="categories && categories.length>0"` for avoid this error

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" [routerLink]=" . 
['/admin/products/new']" mdbWavesEffect>New Products</button>
<table mdbTable >
<thead >
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngIf="categories && categories.length>0">
  <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of categories">
    <td>{{el?.title}}</td>
    <td>{{el?.price}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

and your 1st console log at line 23 is telling you what is happening.

Somehow you are assigning 1 of type '**number**' to the variable categories, probably best to check first if the data is an array before assigning it or just update your 'prservice.fetchproducts' observable to always return an array

```
this.subscription = this.prservice.fetchproducts
  .subscribe((data) => {
    if(Array.isArray(data)) { 
      this.categories=data
      console.log(this.categories)
    }
  });
```